# Finding interval overlap between two tables

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables that have top_depth, bottom_depth, lith_type.  One defines the different layers found in a borehole and the other define where samples are extracted in each of the layers.

I would like to find all samples that intersects the layer boundaries. Although, I was able to solve my problem, I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.  This is what I did:

```
CREATE TABLE lithology ( official_name TEXT, top_depth FLOAT, bottom_depth FLOAT, lith_type TEXT );
INSERT INTO lithology VALUES('B1', 0, 3,'SC'); 
INSERT INTO lithology VALUES('B1', 3, 11,'SS');
INSERT INTO lithology VALUES('B1', 11, 20,'STS');
INSERT INTO lithology VALUES('B1', 1, 21, 'SS');

CREATE TABLE sample_data ( official_name TEXT, sample_id TEXT, top_depth FLOAT, bottom_depth FLOAT, lith_type TEXT );
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES('B1', 1, 1, 2,'SC');
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES('B1', 2, 3, 4,'SS');
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES('B1', 3, 6, 7,'SS');
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES('B1', 4, 10.5, 11.5,'SS');
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES('B1', 5, 14, 15,'SS');
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES('B1', 6, 19, 20,'SS');

select 
    L.official_name, S.sample_id,
    L.top_depth, L.bottom_depth, L.lith_type,
    S.top_depth, S.bottom_depth, S.lith_type
from
    lithology L, sample_data S
where
    L.official_name = S.official_name 
and
    (S.bottom_depth > L.top_depth and L.top_depth > S.top_depth or
    S.bottom_depth > L.bottom_depth and L.bottom_depth > S.top_depth or
    S.top_depth < L.top_depth and S.bottom_depth > L.bottom_depth )
order by L.official_name,S.sample_id
```

This should show that sample_id=4 is the sample to check.

Comment: Since this is a GIS it's likely there will be some sort of "overlap" or "intersect" function, though the data would likely have to be expressed as an array of points.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to work on this is to follow Martin Fowler's (and many others as well) technique: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap

**Note:** SQL Server syntax

```
create table Layers (layer_top_depth int, layer_bottom_depth int, layer_lith_type int);
create table Samples (sample_top_depth int, sample_bottom_depth int, sample_lith_type int);
go
insert into layers  values(4, 7, 1) ; 
insert into layers  values(6, 8, 2);
insert into layers  values(5, 6, 3);
insert into Samples values(6, 7, 1);
insert into Samples values(6, 7, 2);
insert into Samples values(3, 8, 3);
go
SELECT L.layer_top_depth, L.layer_bottom_depth, L.layer_lith_type, 
       S.sample_top_depth, S.sample_bottom_depth, S.sample_lith_type
 FROM Layers L
   JOIN Samples S ON
       (L.layer_top_depth <= s.sample_bottom_depth AND
        S.sample_top_depth <= L.layer_bottom_depth);
go
drop table Layers;
drop table samples;
```

If the samples *at boundary layer should not be reported*, replace the comparison of `<=` with `<` as mentioned by **ypercubeᵀᴹ** and is shown below:

```
SELECT L.layer_top_depth, L.layer_bottom_depth, L.layer_lith_type, 
       S.sample_top_depth, S.sample_bottom_depth, S.sample_lith_type
 FROM Layers L
   JOIN Samples S ON
       (L.layer_top_depth < s.sample_bottom_depth AND
        S.sample_top_depth < L.layer_bottom_depth);
```

The `lyth_type` is just riding along in this since you did not mention how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Martin Fowler's website.  I see you have both layers crossing and samples.  In my use case, layers rarely cross (caused by data entry error), but samples can intersect layers.  Samples at  layer boundary should not be reported.

Comment: @cgs_bob then this answrr can be easily adjusted to SQLite. You probably just need to change those `<=` to `<`.

Comment: Should official_name be in the join?

Comment: @MichaelGreen - If the official_name would help you organize the data, then it should be included.